# Issue with a regular expression in date format

Tags: php, regex

I want to validate the date format `YYYY-MM-DD`in PHP. But something is wrong and I can't find it? The regular expression keeps telling me the format is wrong, when it is right.

```
$datePattern = '/^(2[0-9][0-9][0-9])\-(0[1-9]|1[0-2]])\-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])$/';  
$date = '2011-11-05';
if(!preg_match($datePattern,$date)){
    die('Wrong format in date!');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `]` in your regular expression (month subexpression) that is not needed. So it should be

```
^(2[0-9][0-9][0-9])\-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it a little bit:

```
/^(2[0-9]{3})-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-1])$/
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra `]` in your regex:

```
'/^(2[0-9][0-9][0-9])\-(0[1-9]|1[0-2]])\-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])$/'
                                     ^
```

drop it.

And regex is not the best tool to validate dates. You should be using the [checkdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) function.